# Update a widget app in two different times, is it possible?

Tags: android

I´m making a widget app and I want a part of it update once a day with  `android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"` and another part **update** every minute with `AlarmManager`. But I think if you use `AlarmManager` you have to put to `android:updatePeriodMillis="0"`. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you can use both updatePeriodMillis and AlarmManager simultaneously. But in any case, you can always rely on AlarmManager for both updates, setting two different "Alarms" for the same widget update.

Comment: Thank you, yes, I´m trying with two alarms

Answer (score 0):

Finally this work (two alarms, one every minute and another every day):

```
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, 
            calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            60000, funtion1(context));

    Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 00);
    calendar2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    calendar2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC,
            calendar2.getTimeInMillis(),
            86400000, funtion2(context));
```